# FQL Query Usage

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-fql

I need to get the posts on my Facebook page using FQL. I tried the query:

```sql
SELECT message FROM stream WHERE source_id= My_Page_ID
```

Then I got the error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "An access token is required to request this resource.",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 104
  }
}
```

Then I tried the same query with access_token:-

```sql
SELECT message FROM stream
  WHERE source_id= My_Page_ID AND access_token = my_access_token
```

Then I got the error

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#602) acces_token is not a member of the stream table.",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 602
  }
}
```

What do I do. How can I solve it. Please provide me an error free FQL query to get POSTs on my Facebook page using C#.net

Answer (score 0):

in the second query, you have added `access_token`, you need to check if **this exists**, I assume it doesn't? try removing this or double checking the `stream` table

```
SELECT message FROM stream
  WHERE source_id= My_Page_ID AND access_token = my_access_token
```

**EDIT**: I have just checked here, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream/, and this column doesn't exist.

Comment: My User access has ** 2 Month  ** validity

Comment: @user2605663, what does this mean?

Answer (score 0):

You query is perfectly correct. You are probably making the call in a wrong way, try like this-

```
$fql = "SELECT message FROM stream
        WHERE source_id= My_Page_ID";

$param = array(
               'method'      => 'fql.query',
               'query'       => $fql,
               'access_token'=> ACCESS_TOKEN,
               'callback'    => ''
              );

$my_result = $facebook->api($param);
```

Also note that you need the permission: `read_stream` to read the stream table